# How to apply conditional formatting to Google Sheet cells based on a calculation in a different, non-static cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet containing churn data for a 24 month period. In the sheet, I've calculated churn MoM as well as the average churn. I want to apply conditional formatting to make a given MoM churn that's 10% higher than the average churn to be dark red. I can achieve that for a particular cell by using the example formula below.

**=H7>(H2+10%)**

I can't figure out how to get that to apply across an entire row (such that for column I it would be =I7>(I2+10%) and so on).
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please try changing your applied range to your specified column I.E, "I:I", if it doesn't work please let me know and also please share a Minimum reproducible sample.

Comment: This made a lot more things red than anticipated :(

Here is a sample file with a few months: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aX6lYdLG6DVvSuIiSnuLC2KJ0udYUj7Cs03fKWK3UJY/edit?usp=sharing

Note: in addition to having it apply across an entire row, I want it to apply to multiple rows (row 7, 13, 19, 25)

Comment: Is your provided Spreadsheet the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you include a sample output situation using your sample input situation in the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @tanaike I added the formula to H7 - that would be the desired result across the entire row and for multiple rows

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `I added the formula to H7 - that would be the desired result across the entire row and for multiple rows`, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No need to apologize! I appreciate your attempt to help. I can achieve my goal (have conditional formatting to make a given MoM churn that's 10% higher than the average churn to be dark red) for a particular cell by using the example formula in H7. But I don't want to have to manually put in a formula for every cell in row 7 and the other rows to apply the conditional formatting.
 My goal was to figure out a custom formula that I could apply across the entire row that would compare that column's MoM churn to the average MoM churn in row 2. I hope this makes more sense!
=H7>(H2+10%)

Answer (score 1):

Try below conditional formatting rule-

```
=H$7>(H$2+10%)
```

Please apply above rule for `H7:Z7` range. It is important to mention proper apply range.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this works.
I have other rows that I want to apply the same logic to (so the first set of churn data is for January 2018 in row 7, but then I have another set of churn data for February 2018 in row 13, then March 2018 in row 19 - I want them all to compare against the average in row 2).

I tried to apply the same custom formula for row 13 but it didn't do anything. I tried to broaden the range to see if it would work but it just made all of column C red (no idea why)